# How to remove echo

Tags: android, webrtc, libjingle, echo-cancellation

I am working on app which do live stream between two android devices. I have got pretty got results like connectivity, video stream. But i am not happy with sound qualtiy there is so echo and noise in sound. This is how i am using audio track

```
localMS = factory.createLocalMediaStream("ARDAMS");
          if(pcParams.videoCallEnabled)
          {
              MediaConstraints videoConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
              videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxHeight", height));
              videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxWidth",  width));
              videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxFrameRate", Integer.toString(pcParams.videoFps)));
              videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("minFrameRate", Integer.toString(pcParams.videoFps)));

              videoSource = factory.createVideoSource(getVideoCapturer(), videoConstraints);
              localMS.addTrack(factory.createVideoTrack("ARDAMSv0", videoSource));
          }

          AudioSource audioSource = factory.createAudioSource(new MediaConstraints());
          localMS.addTrack(factory.createAudioTrack("ARDAMSa0", audioSource));

          mListener.onLocalStream(localMS);
```

So i am looking for way to remove echo and noise cancellation. any help and guidance will be very much appreciated.

Comment: how can i use webrtc aec in my current code. I didn't find any doc regarding that.

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249144/echo-and-noise-in-sound-webrtc-android/31407309#31407309 please, it should be helpful

Answer (score 0):

**Possible solutions to solve sound quality problems:**

- Reduce video resolution to allow more bandwidth for audio
- Don't run two clients in the same physical room (sound from the speaker on one computer enters the microphone of the other computer)
- Reduce the speaker volume.
- Use a headset.
- Use a conference microphone/speaker with built-in noise cancelling.
- Android implement noise cancelling API (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/NoiseSuppressor.html)